# How to pass a 2D (multidimentional) array when using a handler in Google App Script?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, parameters, google-apps-script, parameter-passing

I have several flex tables with their own data sets and a reset button. When a user presses the reset button I would like to clear the flex table and repopulate the flex table with the original data which is stored in a 2-dimensional array. I know how to clear the flex table but repopulating the flex table is giving me problems. I tried to save the 2D array to a hidden object like so:

```
var hidArry = app.createHidden("myArry", my2Darray).setId('HIDArry').setName('HIDArry');
```

In another function where I created the button, I added the hidden object to the button's handler.

```
var buttonHandler = app.createServerHandler('ResetData').addCallbackElement(app.getElementById('HIDArry'));
var button = app.createButton("Reset", buttonHandler);
```

In the function 'ResetData' I tried to call the array like so:

```
e.parameter.HIDArry
```

and

```
e.parameter.myArry
```

However, neither way seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your handler gets called, all parameters are strings. Thus you first need to json.stringify your array and store that string in your hidden (or a hidden text field is what I usually use).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So my 2D array has a mix of strings and numbers (don't know if that matters). When I try to use JSON.stringify and pass it to a textbox I have problems. This is what I did: 
    var temp = JSON.stringify(my2Darray);
    var hidArry = app.createTextBox().setId('HIDArry').setName('HIDArry').setValue(temp);

It seems when I get to here my script returns an error. I am new to scripting and am unfamiliar with json.stringify.

Comment: debug it to see where the erros comes from (use logger.log for example). stringify simply converts it to a string, you should be able to setValue

Comment: Ok, it seems saving it that way actually worked. My array now looks something like this in the textbox: [["test1", "text2",7,""],["text3","",4,""],["text4","",2,""],["text5","",8,""], ....] The error seems to be from trying to call it back from the handler function. When I try to create a label using app.add(app.createLabel(e.parameter.HIDArry)); I get "undefinded". And if I try to save it like this var temp = e.parameter.HIDArry; that's where I get the error.

Comment: the error must be comming from somewhere else. its just a string like any other. you need JSON.parse later when you want to convert it back into an array.

Comment: Found what was causing the error. This worked perfectly.  Thanks.